# Can't set memory settings for `sbt start`

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory, sbt, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to run `sbt start` in a Play Framework application written in Scala, on a machine that is an *ec2 t2.micro* instance on AWS. But i can't because *There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.*

The machine has 1GB of memory, but in practice 930MB of free memory to use while running the remaining of OS processes. It is Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. The app is small, cute.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000d5550000, 715849728, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /app/incoming/hs_err_pid9709.log
```

[Here is the link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kovacshuni/7fd87d5c86d236ac4bcc/raw/58784a64d67249d37976eee4a10b1adc1559bfbb/hs_err_pid9709.log) to the log file for more info.

Inside i see `jvm_args: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m ...` despite i set my JVM args in so many different ways to something else but no effect.

With these arguments `-Xss1m -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` I tried everything:

- setting JVM args in /usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/conf/sbtopts
- same in /usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/conf/sbtconfig.txt
- supplying the args directly when running: `sbt -J-Xss1m -J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled start`
- already set `fork in run := true` in build.sbt
- `javaOptions in run += "-Xmx512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"` in build.sbt

Neither of them helps. The same lame 1024 things appear in the logs every time i run the app. Please help.

Comment: Bump. Still no clue.

Comment: I've misinterpreted your question and thought you whanted to increase memory allocated to jvm when you actually wanted to decrease it. You still should be able to use my suggestion to do it, but with different memory amount. I've updated my answer, let me know whether it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 14):

Also struggled with setting jvm memory args for `sbt` on Linux in the past (on Windows you can tweak `sbtconfig.txt` but this and all other places where you can specify `SBT_OPTS` I could find doesn't work on Linux for some reason).

Last time I've solved this by using `-mem <amount>` option of `sbt` itself.

So, in your case you should try something like this:

```
$ sbt -mem 512 start
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today with EC2 nano-instance. Solved it this way:

```
cd /etc/sbt-launcher-packaging/ 
sudo nano sbtopts
```

Then uncomment -mem option. I've set it to 256 and after that I can normally run sbt on nano-instance.
A sample piece of this config file after edited:

```
# Path to local Ivy repository (default: ~/.ivy2)
#
#-ivy ~/.ivy2

# set memory options
#
-mem   256

# Use local caches for projects, no sharing.
#
#-no-share
```